# C# does not run or delete file

Tags: c#, batch-file

This C# program makes a batch file runs it and then is supposed to delete the file. When I run the program it makes the batch file and executes it perfectly if the last if statement is not there. But with the last if statement it makes the file and deletes it but does not make any changes.

```
 string batFile;
 batFile = genBat(textBox1.Text);
 string path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\blocksite.bat";

 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
 {
       sw.WriteLine(@batFile);
       sw.Close();
 }

       Process.Start(path);

 if(File.Exists(path))
 {
       File.Delete(path)
 }
```

Comment: sw.WriteLine(@batFile); ???

Comment: `batFile = genBat(textBox1.Text);` is a string of what to write into the batch file.

Comment: That's lovely, but `@batfile` ?

Comment: What is the batch file doing that you are not able to do via code? You can add the following line to you batch file: Del %0

Comment: @FJam: You don't need to use `@` operator to a normal variable like this.

Comment: Remove `sw.Close();` - the `using` scope takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably what happens is that you are managing to delete the .bat file before the `cmd.exe` process can read and process it. You'll need to wait for the process that you start with `Process.Start` to finish before deleting the file. Like this:

```
using (var process = Process.Start(path)) {
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

---

As an aside, I do wonder why you feel the need to create the .bat file in a directory where you are not supposed to write. You could readily create the .bat file under the temporary directory. If you need the working directory to be a different directory then you can readily specify that when starting the process.

Comment: oh it is made in that directory because it is changing the host file. in that directory .

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to create the .bat file there to do that. Just make the process have that directory as its working directory.

Comment: I though this would have made it in an update, but no, and particularly because it's likely you'll get the most coverage now, I would like to highlight that Process should be disposed of.

Comment: @GrantThomas Sorry, I was not paying attention. I've updated my answer, shamelessly using the correction that you provide. I did upvote your answer though. I hope that's OK.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not a problem at all, just trying to be conscientious. (:

Answer (score 4):

There's a good chance you're deleting the file before the process has actually started processing. You should store the `Process` returned by `Process.Start` (as a general rule, you should never just neglect the returned result of an operation in .NET) and use `WaitForExit`, and *then* delete the file.

```
using (var process = Process.Start(path)) {
  process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Remembering that a `Process` is a disposable thing, it's an even worse idea to neglect the result.